# Loop calls process that takes a long time to complete. How do I break out of it?

Tags: bash, loops, kill-process

I got to this solution yesterday with help from here (it's finding a list of directories to process with HandBrakeCLI, and putting the results in a hard-coded directory):

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir=/Volumes/VolumeName
dest_dir=/Volumes/OtherName

export dest_dir # export allows use by subprocesses!

find "$source_dir" -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -exec bash -c '
  for dir; do
    name=${dir%/VIDEO_TS}
    name=${name##*/}
    ./HandBrakeCLI -i "$dir" -o "$dest_dir/$name.m4v"
  done
' _ {} +
```

The shell script works fine, but if I try to stop it by killing the main process:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

it seems to work but then comes back to life and calls HandBrakeCLI with the next file in the list generated by find.

Is there a way of reliably stopping the whole thing?  I'm assuming that somehow the future calls to the CLI are being queued/cached, but could someone explain what's happening please?

Comment: I suggest to use `trap` command. See `help trap`.

Comment: Thanks.  I can see the principle, but can't quite figure out the application here.  If I put something like 'trap \'some code\' 2' at the top of the file, I don't think that's adding anything as I can already send ctrl-C to the main script.  So, do I put it somewhere in the do...done loop and what should I do in the code part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is made unnecessarily complex by invoking bash from find.  I suggest iterating over the output of find.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source_dir=/Volumes/VolumeName
dest_dir=/Volumes/OtherName

find "${source_dir}" -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" | while read dir; do
  name=${dir%/VIDEO_TS}
  name=${name##*/}
  ./HandBrakeCLI -i "${dir}" -o "${dest_dir}/${name}.m4v"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I try this, I have two issues: i. with the curly brackets around the vars in the HandBrakeCLI call I get an error of 'bad substitution' and ii. if i remove these brackets the loop only runs once (even though there is more than one directory returned from find).

Comment: You could try debugging the script further by adding an 'echo' in front of the './HandBrakeCLI'.  This will allow you to see exactly how the command will be called without actually running it.

Comment: As I said in my other post, there's an issue with ffmpeg consuming all the input.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there's a problem with using find piped to while loop as suggested by @JonNailey with HandBrakeCLI (and other processes that call ffmpeg): it 'sucks up' all the input from the find command and starves the loop.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089 for details.

The solution I chose was to put this redirection on the line calling HandBrakeCLI:

```
</dev/null
```